# Developing android app with emulator

Tags: android

To make android app for social network websites, at which point should one start using actual mobile device for testing ? Is it possible to develop whole app testing from emulator itself ?

Comment: The question is too vague, provide a more concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the emulator for all practical purposes up until you are ready to test your app with an actual test group. Obviously, install it on your own device first and test yourself prior to distributing to the test group.

Comment: I will improve the question as I gro in understanding of android more. I think for all practical purposes it is possble for me to develop most of apps on emulator.